# 'Power of' in python

Tags: python, math

Why is it when:

```
>> b = -1
>> b**2
1
```

But:

```
>> -1**2
-1
```

If i import the math library, it's no problem.

```
>> from math import pow
>> pow(b,2)
1.0
>> pow(-1,2)
1.0
```

Comment: add parenthesis (-1)**2

Comment: Thanks that worked. How does encapsulating a single number change anything?

Comment: Because `-1**2` is grouped as `-(1**2)`, which of course is just `-1`.

Comment: you don't need the math module to use pow, python have it built-in and with more options too

Comment: You know how `-x^2` in math means `-(x^2)`? That applies to `-1^2` too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the Python documentation:
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator

> The power operator binds more tightly than unary operators on its
>   left; it binds less tightly than unary operators on its right.
>
> Thus, in an unparenthesized sequence of power and unary operators, the
>   operators are evaluated from right to left (this does not constrain
>   the evaluation order for the operands): `-1**2` results in `-1`.

Comment: This is funny because the documentation contains an example that exactly matches the OP's question

Comment: Thanks for that astro

Answer (score 6):

It is related with operator precedence.

Try

```
(-1)**2
```

`**` is being evaluated first and then `-`. Hence, you got `-1`.

In case of `pow` function, `-1` is being evaluated first.

See reference on https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator

Comment: Oh, like -(1**2), thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Since its working on 1 not -1 as a whole. This will give expected result.

```
(-1)**2
```

Comment: This isn't as useful as the other answers since it doesn't get into precedence, but I'm baffled as to why it's currently at -2 while the other two are at 3 and 4. This is a helpful answer.

Comment: Not sure , but I guess because its identical to @karakfa  comment  and the rest are just overrated