# Is there a way of typing a squared number?

Tags: python, math, numbers

Is it possible to type a squared number in python?
Or how to type for example 5 to the power of 2

Comment: `5**2` is 5 to the power of 2 ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Power of' in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34603595/power-of-in-python)

Answer (score -1):

number**power

As Joran Beasley said you only type **2 next to the number to take it to the power of 2.

In python we multiply with * so ** is multiplying two times, which is square. however *** is an error and **3 is cubic.

however you can also define a method

```
def power(number,n):
    x=1
    for n in range(n):
       x=number*x
    return x

print(power(5,8))
```

Comment: I was asking if there is any way of typing a square number in a string for example

Comment: you can not define a int type in an str type. It is a type error.

Comment: why did you flag my answer as not useful? I am not helping anyone from now on.

Comment: Im so sorrt it was an accident

Comment: Its okay, dont worry